# Adverb for approximate numbers

Tags: classical-latin, word-choice, adverb, numbers, numerals

In classical Latin, what is the best adverb for describing approximate numbers?
If several work well, are there any differences?
I mean saying things like "I have about ten euros".
I would translate that as *decem fere eurones habeo*.
My preference is *fere*, but there are other words in the same direction (*ferme, circa, prope, quasi, iuxta, paene*) and I do not know if there is a typical classical idiom.

Comment: I'm glad you asked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already hit upon all the words I would use except *ad* as a preposition. For example, Cicero uses [ad quadriginta natus esse](https://archive.org/stream/copiouscriticale00smit#page/2/mode/2up/search/about) as a synonym for *fere*. But in general, *circa* and *circiter* both work.

To my ears, *paene* would mean "almost, but not quite" rather than "around that neighborhood." Others are all general idioms for "approximately." I wouldn't, for example, use *paene decem* if you *might* have 11 euros. That word, with some unusual exceptions, seems more to mean "just about" rather than "about." See the L&S entry on it.

Comment: Thank you! I did wonder if I should include *ad* in the list but decided to leave it out. Do you happen to know which of these words are most common?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I don't know 100%, but from my overall impression, *circa* is most common.

Comment: *Circa* is certainly the one which survived with that meaning, though whether that says anything about classical usage is debatable.